# Shutting Down my Solo 401(K) plan

Tags: united-states, income-tax, retirement

I recently shutdown my individual 401(K) plan at E*Trade. There was also a Roth 401(K) plan also. I plan to file form 5500EZ just once to cover both plans. Is that okay?

I just spoke to E*Trade and they inform me that they are considered two separate plans. Therefore, I conclude I need to file form 5500EZ twice. Once for each plan. Do I have that right?

I am in the United States.

Comment: Does your balance exceed 250K?  I think you would file one form per plan. If they consider them different plans, then you would file one for each that exceeds 250K.  You may want to call the irs for clarification.

Comment: @PeteB. Neither plan has 250K. Combined they do not have 250K. However, I shut down the plan this year so I need to file form 5500EZ. Since they are different plans I need to file the form twice, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

So I am getting the same kind of info from my Fidelity one-particpant plan that I also want to shut down.  The latest instructions are for 2010 and from those instructions:

> You do not have to file Form 5500-EZ for the 2019 plan year for a
> one-participant plan if the total of the plan's assets and the assets
> of all other one-participant plans maintained by the employer at the
> end of the 2019 plan year does not exceed $250,000, unless 2019 is the
> final plan year of the plan. For more information on final plan years,
> see Final Return, later.

[Reference](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i5500ez.pdf)

I am just going to shut down my plan and ignore what the reps for Fidelity say.  They have given me tax advice before that is in direct conflict with my group that does my taxes.

Comment: What advice are you referring to? Fidelity doesn't have a Roth Solo 401(k) so presumably not about filing two Form 5500-EZs.